# Rails has_many : Why does create_model not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, has-many

I think I'm missing something easy here... but can't figure it out.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
  has_many :events
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :start, :end, :all_day, :url
  belongs_to :user
end

u1 = User.create name: "Bob", email: "bob@what.com", password: "asdfasdf"
u1.create_event(start: 3.days.from_now)
```

-->

```
undefined method `create_event' for #<User:0x007f918cbbf7b8>
```

However,

```
u1.events << Event.create!(start: 3.days.from_now)
```

works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't see create_event defined on User. You can also use

```
u1.events.build(:start => 3.days.from_now)
u1.save
```

Fascinated to see that

```
u1.events << Event.create!(start: 3.days.from_now)
```

works. Although, I do think it is a bit obtuse and may not be immediately clear to a casual reader of the code.

Comment: For `has_many` associations, the method you want is `u1.events.create(...)`

Answer (score 6):

You have defined `has_many` association:

```
has_many :events
```

So, if you want to create object you can use these methods:

```
# create new object, but not insert to database
u1.events.build(...)

# create new object and auto call `save` method to insert to database
u1.events.create(...)
```

You use `u1.create_event`, this will correct when you define `has_one` association:

```
has_one :event
```

So, you will have these methods to create object:

```
# create new object, but not insert to database
u1.build_event(...)

# create new object and auto call `save` method to insert to database
u1.create_event(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - spot on.  Someone else beat you to the punch though :)

Comment: I just want to make a clear for you, but he answered first, so you want to accept his answer :)